# Windows Server 2016 DNS response

Tags: windows-server-2016

After publishing a system on IIS, I did speed tests. I usually spend a bit of time on DNS requests on GTMetrix (connecting from Canada to a Germany located server). There is only one system on the server.

Before publishing, I took a different domain name and took the test. The DNS time was not that long, and the entry time from Canada was 4 seconds. We could get the amount we wanted, but after we started broadcasting with the real domain we created more than 40 records on forward lookup zones (with relation to other servers). When we tested again, we saw slowness. But I don't understand why. We disabled recursive interrogation. It was a small difference, but we still didn't get a yield like in the test. What might be the reasons?

Here's an example.
[GTMetrix Score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iSDh.jpg)

Comment: What is the latency tested from another German location? Is the server under heavy CPU/RAM load?

Comment: Here's task manager: https://i.hizliresim.com/NZDVMQ.jpg

Comment: Can you do more tests from different locations? Eventually some closer to your current location?

Comment: You can see to others which closer to our current location: https://gtmetrix.com/compare/Z47pIuWU/P1sUGMkD

They're responding faster.